# Complex SQL query to Magento

Tags: admin, grid, sql

I need to make a complex mysql query into a Magento collection to present in an admin grid. Query is:

```
SELECT g.increment_id AS magento_order_number,
       c.increment_id AS rcs_number,
       g.created_at AS date_entered,
       if(o.iorder_salesrep_email IS NOT NULL
          AND o.iorder_position_id IS NOT NULL, 'iOrder', 'eComm') AS order_system,
       group_concat(concat(oi.sku,' - ',CAST(oi.qty_ordered AS UNSIGNED))) AS products
FROM sales_flat_order_grid g,
     customer_entity c,
     sales_flat_order_item oi,
     sales_flat_order o
WHERE g.entity_id = oi.order_id
  AND c.entity_id = g.customer_id
  AND o.entity_id = g.entity_id
  AND o.store_id != 2
GROUP BY g.entity_id;
```

and i have absolutely no idea how to make it work.
So far i have a couple of joins but im pretty far from the expected results. Any suggestions or resources to handle this?

Comment: Possibly related: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9187/how-can-i-write-this-sql-query-following-the-magento-way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround**

If you're happy with a slightly less efficient workaround

1. Set up `your_custom_method()` in `Grid.php`, and
2. Call this method from the `_prepareColumns()` function, also in Grid.php

You'd need to orientate your grid around a custom model that you predefine. You could then assign this model the fields that you're interested in. The `your_custom_method()` would hence truncate your model's table on load & repopulate it accordingly.

Granted you use direct SQL statements to do so, this should run in less than 2 seconds for a dataset of < 20000. (From my experience).

Comment: I tried something similar like passing the raw SQL query result as the collection to the grid and i failed. This task has been postponed for a sprint or so, once i get the chance to try that again i will try this

Comment: Sure thing, if/when you do, give me a shout if you run into any hassles. I have this exact functionality setup in quite a few instances.

Answer (score 1):

I love converting SQL to Magento collections syntax, don't get me wrong. but I'm on my phone at the moment.

So I'll suggest something else - and I'm probably going to get hammered for this - but here's another way of thinking:

Why not make this a **MySQL view** and then access it as if it were a flat table? That would allow you to access it as if it were a flat collection. This would probably be considered an antipattern and some may scoff at me - but it's certainly *an* approach. In my opinion any approach that works for you and is somewhat maintainable is a decent approach.

One criteria that would prevent you from using the MySQL view strategy, though, would be if you need to lazy-load the collection (it is modified downstream).

There is a module coded by Vinai Kopp and the team at Magento Live UK that allows you to set any flat table as an admin grid with just some configuration xml setup:

http://vinaikopp.com/2014/07/13/magentolive-uk-hackathon/

https://github.com/MagentoHackathonUK2014/Magehack_Autogrid

Comment: I saw the Autogrid module yesterday too and i think it might serve well, but its complex to add community code to this project. I will try the View approach and let you know. Thank you Phil!